# value selected for java script function to PHP without cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a date picker in javascript where i set the date and time as need. when i log the var value it prints fine. but if i send it to PHP page it print just date not the time value

```html
<form action="datetest.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="birthday" value="start" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

```js
var today = new Date();

$(function() {
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "timePickerIncrement": 60,
    "startDate": today,
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be:

You can place a hidden input next to the submit button. like this:

```
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="start" />
<input type="hidden" name="birthdayValue" id="birthdayValue" value="" />
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Login</button>
</form>
```

Then you can set it in your JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "timePickerIncrement": 60,
    "startDate": today,
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00'));
  $('#birthdayValue').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00'));
});
});
```

Then when you submit the form, birthdayValue will be sent to the server.

I hope it helps

Comment: <?php
 $user = $_GET['birthdayValue'];
 

 echo $user;
?>

Comment: Some browsers do not accept the Space character in the GET requests.This seems to be the problem. You have two solutions: 1- Change the form method to the post and receive at the server side by post method. 2: Use the encodeURI(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00')) JavaScript function to convert spaces to %20 character

Comment: will try and update after a while.. thanks for the advice